# Redis Internal error in RDB; Hash listpack integrity check failed

Tags: redis, archlinux, redis-server

I am running a redis-server (Redis server v=7.2.1 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.3.0 bits=64 build=130244e4bf5b7de2) on a computer which runs archlinux (6.5.5-arch1-1).

After a forced shutdown I got this error when trying to run the redis-server:

```
36140:M 10 Oct 2023 20:58:09.582 # Internal error in RDB reading offset 98566134, function at rdb.c:2456 -> Hash listpack integrity check failed.
[offset 0] Checking RDB file aof.aof.3762.base.rdb
```

The redis-server runs under the following configuration:

```
port 200
bind 127.0.0.1
appendonly yes
appendfilename aof.aof
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
save ""
```

How can I fix the database to get a working Redis server with all or most of my data?